# How to deploy a Zend Framework app on Heroku?

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, heroku, facebook-php-sdk

Basically for a Facebook tab I have a PHP app and want Heroku to use the 'public' folder as the web server's root folder instead of pointing to the very root of the app. Any help would be awesome as it seems Heroku doesn't have a ton of documentation around it's config options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not yet at least. They only offer the Facebook app hosting. I have gone with PHPFog for quick PHP hosting now.

EDIT: PHPFog is no more, now they have AppFog.

Answer (score 1):

I hosted my php codeigniter project on heroku lastmonth, so unless there is a server side configuration needed for your project. You should be able to host your zend project by pushing it as git repository to heroku. Just follow these tutorials.

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2YlEIMrGxA
2. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of that but [Heroku's website](http://www.heroku.com/) says "Agile deployment for Ruby, Node.js, Clojure, Java, Python, and Scala.".  But since there's no mention of PHP I think you can't deploy your Zend app on Heroku.

EDIT : my assertion was false, see comments

Comment: Heroku is experimenting with PHP and offers PHP hosting only to FB apps at the moment.

Comment: Is it mention anywhere on their site ?

Comment: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook -- just search for 'PHP', it should be in the top 5th of the page.

Comment: Wow ... this is scary that's the first thing you can find... When I googled PHP Heroku I found a competitors website as first link.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not sure how long Heroku have been experimenting with PHP and if they will ever go into production proper with it. Seems like its more of a side venture than a core thing for them

Comment: The kind of beta you won't bet your business on ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thats not entirely correct (or no longer correct) - if you put a repository with an index.php in the root up it seems to recognise that as a php app.